# Trying to learn modern server setup, need to get the layering correct

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, docker

In a traditional LAMP server we have Linux running Apache running MySQL and PHP.

I'm currently early in the process of teaching myself a more modern approach as a preamble for teaching myself node.js. So far I have successfully got Ubuntu running on a virtual box, but I'm a little confused by what elements need to be built on each other to finish creating my server.

I want to run node.js on top of docker using composer, git and possibly redis (this may need to be a seperate server, I'm not entirely clear yet). Then I want a similar setup to run php/mysql so my node applications can use the strengths of those technologies as well. This seems sufficiently similar to a production environment to make for a good learning environment.

So I'm thinking the correct layering is:

- virtual box
- running ubuntu with composer, git and other utilities installed
- running a docker image
- containing a node.js or php/mysql server as appropriate
- Which in turn runs the usual code and frameworks

Does that look right? I'm most uncertain about the role of docker - whether it should contain the ubuntu image as well and where the composer and git installations should be sat (on the os layer or the docker layer?).

General advice / criticism of this setup would be appreciated.

Comment: You should probably start by just trying the setup. There are quite a few how-to's out on the internet just a Google search away that walk you through this process, as well as plenty of documents explaining each of these systems which you should probably study.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Your Virtualbox Ubuntu is the main server, where you should have:

1. Docker
2. git and all utilities
3. your content (html, php, css, js, etc.)

Docker allows you to install containerized applications, i.e.:

1. Nginx and php-pfm
2. MySQL
3. NodeJS

You should see them as applications, nothing more than that. You should have one container per application, so when you want to use a different version of, let's say, MySQL, you should destroy the container and create a new one. Each container should expose the port it needs to be accessed from (e.g. port 80 or 443 for nginx). Also, the container should be given access to folders on the main server where the source files reside (and are version controlled with git). This way, destroying a container should be the same as uninstalling a program.